# how to change font size tableOutput in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm attempting to make tableOutput's fonts larger. I look for examples, try to apply the answer to my code, but it doesn't work.

My code :

`mainPanel(span(tableOutput('tabledata'), style = "font-size:80%"))`

`mainPanel(span(tableOutput('tabledata'), style = "font-size:8px"))`

`mainPanel(span(tableOutput('tabledata'), style = "font-size:8.0pt"))`

However, when I tried to modify the color. It does work.

`mainPanel(span(tableOutput('tabledata'), style = "color:white"))`

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! All options work fine for me. Perhaps you could provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a minimal and working shiny app.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`div(tableOutput("tableName"), style = "font-size:80%")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the output is unchanged.

Comment: It works for me, if u need better help provide a minimal reproducible of your code like it was said in the comment section.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm aware of the issue because I'm using theme = shinytheme ("superhero"). It doesn't works when I adjust the font size in tableOutput. However, when I adjust the font size of tableOutput using theme = shinytheme("united"), it works. 
more questions The font size can't be changed for the theme superhero , right?

I practice understanding shiny using this github.
https://github.com/dataprofessor/code/blob/master/shiny/003-play-golf/app.R